# Can't call method "setValue" on an undefined value - perl

Tags: html, perl, parsing, undefined, setvalue

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use 5.010;
use HTML::HTML5::Parser;

open (FILE, '<links.txt') ;

my @lines = <FILE>;
my $i;
my $a = $lines[$i];

my $xml = HTML::HTML5::Parser->load_html(location => $a) ;
```

got error:
"Can't call method "setValue" on an undefined value at C:/Dwimperl/perl/site/lib/
HTML/HTML5/Parser/TagSoupParser.pm line 2946"

I've tried to insert an if and define value first but it doesn't work.

I'm at the beginning of learning Perl, could anyone here help me with this?

Comment: this doesn't compile for me due to `$i` not being defined.  Are you missing some code?

Comment: The code is useless without the data that causes the problem to surface. (But be sure to trim the HTML down to the minimum needed to generate the error before posting it!) And that's assuming the error isn't in the code you actually ran (rather than the useless code you posted). You've failed to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply here! So the issue for me is that some links do generate the error and some don't. I don't know if it's the link itself (I've tried removing the rest of the code - just as above -  and still nothing) or the html of the webpage ? How can I check which elements do generate the error - split html into a few pieces and parse it separately?

Comment: First off, your code shouldn't run at all because ``$i`` is left undefined. If you need help with the code, please provide something that runs. Second, if you have problem with a particular line in ``links.txt``, try finding it. You can just print each line as it is being processed to find out which one fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use 5.010;
use HTML::HTML5::Parser;
use Try::Tiny;

open (my $FILE, '<', 'links.txt') ;
my @lines = <$FILE>;
my $i = 0;
foreach my $a (@lines) {
    my $xml = try {
        HTML::HTML5::Parser->load_html(location => $a)
    } catch {
        warn "Bad line [$i][$a]";
        warn "Actual error: $_";
    };
    $i++;
}
```

I've cleaned up your code with my best guess as to how it's actually supposed to be structured, and added a try/catch block (using `Try::Tiny`) to demonstrate a method of identifying your problem lines.

You need to identify what input is causing the problem before you can really diagnose the problem.

Comment: I couldn't find which element of html caused the problem but I've silenced errors with Try::Tiny on "bad" links and it's more than enough as for me. Thanks a ton for your help!